# Separate a string using a regex

Tags: lua, pattern-matching, lua-patterns

```
 _, _, XYZ, Path, filename  = string.find("re32:HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\SOFTWARE\\XYZ\\Assistant\\Active ", "(%w+):(.+)\\(.*)")

print(XYZ)  
print(Path)    
print(filename)
```

The above code outputs:

```
 re32
 HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\XYZ\Assistant\
 Active
```

I need the output in below form--that is, instead of three groups, I need four:

```
re32
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE
SOFTWARE\XYZ\Assistant\
Active
```

What has to be done in this case?

Answer (score 1):

```
XYZ, RootKey, Path, filename = ([[re32:HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFT WARE\XYZ\Assistant\Active ]]):match ( [[(%w+):([^\]+)(.+)\(.*)]])
```

Use [[]] instead of "" to stop escape sequences.

Answer (score 0):

```
_, _, XYZ, RootKey, Path, filename = string.find("re32:HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\XYZ\Assistant\Active ", "(%w+):(.-)\(.+)\(.*)")

print(XYZ)
print(RootKey)
print(Path)
print(filename)
```

Should produce

```
re32

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE

SOFTWARE\\XYZ\\Assistant\\

Active
```

Comment: _, _, XYZ,test, Path, filename = string.find("re32:HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\SOFTWARE\\XYZ\\Assistant\\Active ", "(%w+):(.+)\\(.+)\\(.*)" )

Print(XYZ)
Print(test)
Print(Path)
Print(filename)

Comment: @Chet, you'll need to also add another variable for additional group you created

Comment: Please verify  Second and third group has to be reversed

Comment: Getting output with your suggestion:

re32
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\SOFTWARE\\XYZ
Assistant
Active 


Expected :

re32
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE
SOFTWARE\\XYZ\\Assistant
Active

Comment: Getting output with your suggestion:

  re32
  HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\SOFTWARE\\XYZ
  Assistant
  Active 


 Expected :

  re32
  HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE
  SOFTWARE\\XYZ\\Assistant
  Active

Comment: Getting output with your suggestion:

  re32

  HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\SOFTWARE\\XYZ

  Assistant
 
  Active 


 Expected :

  re32

  HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE

  SOFTWARE\\XYZ\\Assistant

  Active

Comment: @Chet just edited the answer... I don't have a compiler handy, but looks like it should work like that.

Comment: ** PLEASE VERFIY THE OUTOUT IT IS NOT WORKING**

Comment: @Chet, can you post what you're getting in your original question? Formatting is not visible in comments, so I'm not entirely sure what is it that you're getting...

Comment: @Chet, ok I see what you're talking about. Fixed the answer. Your second pattern should be ungreedy.

Answer (score 0):

You can have named groups in regular expressions.
example:- (/group1\[0-9])(abc)
(replace "/" with "<" and "\" with ">" in above example)
this regx will match "3abc" and you can get the matched number by choosing the group name(group1) in the  match.
refeer this http://www.regular-expressions.info/named.html

Comment: Regex in LUA I need yoy are talking about C#

Comment: PLEAse help with the LUA Regex

Answer (score 0):

```
_, _, XYZ, RootKey, Path, filename = string.find(
    "re32:HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\SOFTWARE\\XYZ\\Assistant\\Active ",
    "(%w+):(.-)\\(.+\\)(.*)")

print(XYZ)
print(RootKey)
print(Path)
print(filename)
```

output:

```
re32
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE
SOFTWARE\XYZ\Assistant\
Active
```

**[See it on ideone.com](http://ideone.com/Y6gbC)**

This answer is essentially the same as Serge's, but the backslashes are properly escaped in the target and pattern strings, and the final backslash is included the third capturing group.

But most importantly, this solution is *tested*.  [Ideone](http://ideone.com/) FTW!